# " undefined property onClickHandler as function" Error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, react-redux, enzyme

[image]I am trying to test `click` function is called or not . but getting this 
error
`Attempted to wrap undefined property onClickHandler as function`

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/oq7kwzrnj5

```
it("check counter increment function is callled", () => {
    const sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
    const spy = sandbox.spy(Counter.prototype, "onClickHandler");
    const wrapper = shallow(<Counter />);
    wrapper.find("button").simulate("click");
    expect(spy.called).toBe(true);
  });
```

Comment: And you've no clue what the english error text means?

Comment: see updates my Question

Comment: Where is the code for your component?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't working because the `onClickHandler` is not a `class` method. You need to make a few adjustments. First, change the method declaration to this:

```
onClickHandler() {
  const incrementCounter = this.state.counter + 1;
  this.setState({
    counter: incrementCounter
  });
};
```

Then in the `constructor` you can do something like this to keep your component binding proper:

```
this.onClickHandler = this.onClickHandler.bind(this);
```

**NOTE:** another option for binding that class method, instead of using the constructor, is to use a library that does it for you. Below is an example of what that might look like.

```
import React from "react";
import autoBindMethods from 'class-autobind-decorator';

class Counter extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      counter: 0
    };
  }

  onClickHandler() {
    const incrementCounter = this.state.counter + 1;
    this.setState({
      counter: incrementCounter
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{this.state.counter}</p>
        <button onClick={this.onClickHandler}>INCREMENT</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

autoBindMethods(Counter);
export default Counter;
```